# Add a count column to a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In addition to have a query that shows columns from two tables where the column NodeGuid match, I want to add a column to each row that contains a count of the total rows in this query that contain the current row's table1.NodeGuid.

```
SELECT table1.NodeGuid
, table2.MarkerGuid mg
, --Need this column which contains a count of the total rows in this query that contain the current row's table1.NodeGuid
FROM table1
   , table2
WHERE table2.NodeGuid = table1.NodeGuid
```

Thank you.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? The 2 are very different RDBMS. Either way, what's wrong with the `COUNT` function here?

Comment: @Larnu Microsoft SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

Comment: Time to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for over 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @Larnu See comment under Gordon's answer.

Comment: This is 2019.  `JOIN` has been around for over 25 years.  Start using it.

Comment: @Eric I do use it. I'll also refer you to my comment under Gordon's answer. It's an old, complex query I'm adding to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use window functions . . . and proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT table1.NodeGuid, table2.MarkerGuid mg,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY table1.NodeGuid) as cnt
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.NodeGuid = table1.NodeGuid
```

Comment: I'm inserting the count column into an existing query that is very complex, but is closer to the example I showed (without a join). Would your count work with the my version (without the join)?

Comment: Seems to work with the query I supplied. Thanks for the Partition By, this must have been where I got stuck.